# Laravel Undefined variable: file

Tags: php, laravel

I have a small app to sell online courses.

Everytime I reset my migrations by doing `php artisan migrate:reset`, I get this error if I try to update a field in my Ecourses edit blade file.

Here's my controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $slugify = new Slugify();

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'price' => 'nullable',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'level_id' => 'required',
        'subtitle' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'video_link' => 'required',
        'document' => 'nullable|file',
        'status' => 'required|integer'

    ]);

    $ecourse = Ecourse::findOrFail($id);
    $ecourse->name = $request->name;
    $ecourse->slug = $slugify->slugify($request->name);
    $ecourse->price = $request->price;
    $ecourse->status = $request->status;
    $ecourse->description = $request->description;
    $ecourse->subtitle = $request->subtitle;
    $ecourse->video_link = $request->video_link;
    $ecourse->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $ecourse->level_id = $request->level_id;

    $document = $request->file('document');

    if ($request->hasFile('document')) {
        $documentFullname = $document->getClientOriginalName();
        $documentName = pathinfo($documentFullname, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $document->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file = time() . '_' . $documentName . '.' . $extension;
        $document->storeAs('public/ecourses-files/', $file );

    }

    $fileToDelete = 'public/ecourses-files'. '/' . $ecourse->document;

    if (Storage::exists($fileToDelete)) {
        Storage::delete($fileToDelete);
    }

    $ecourse->document = $file;

    $ecourse->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.ecourses.index')->with('success','Formation mise à jour');
}
```

The error is due to this line `$ecourse->document = $file;` and to make it work I have to comment it, update my Ecourse blade and then uncomment it.

I really don't know what's happening here...

Any help or explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks and take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like that `$request->hasFile('document')` return false in this case this block of code will never run

```
if ($request->hasFile('document')) {
    $documentFullname = $document->getClientOriginalName();
    $documentName = pathinfo($documentFullname, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = $document->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file = time() . '_' . $documentName . '.' . $extension;
    $document->storeAs('public/ecourses-files/', $file );
}
```

So there is no variable `$file` is defined, to solve this you can do

```
$file = null;

if ($request->hasFile('document')) {
    $documentFullname = $document->getClientOriginalName();
    $documentName = pathinfo($documentFullname, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = $document->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file = time() . '_' . $documentName . '.' . $extension;
    $document->storeAs('public/ecourses-files/', $file );
}
```

This will solve the problem but in case that column `document` cannot be null it will give you an error so you you will have to make it `required` in validation rules and check why `$request->hasFile('document')` returns false

Comment: Thank you @mmabdelgawad, it worked ! Do I have to add this `$file = null;` in my store method as well?

Comment: If you have the same situation in `store` method. Yes you have to not get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative solution**, check `$file` with `isset()`, if not define then define it, as like :

```
if(!isset($file)){
  $file = null;
}
$ecourse->document = $file;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an operator for this:

```
$course->document = $file ?? null;
```